# Xpath Attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hello I have the following XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Data> 
<x>3</x>  
<Document1 id="123" filename="/test/dev/fileA.txt"/>  
<Document2 id="123" filename="/test/dev/fileB.txt"/>  
<Document3 id="123" filename="/test/dev/fileC.txt"/>  
<Document4 id="123" filename="/test/dev/fileD.txt"/> 
</Data>
```

I need with Xpath 1.0 to be able to retrieve a specific filename using the x variable.

Something like:

```
/Data/Document[x]/@filename
```

I need to be able to retrieve a specific filename base on the value of x.  Is it possible?  Please let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But why do you want to design your input xml format like this? It would be much better to use the id attribute to select the right document rather than the element name, for many reasons.

Reasons include:

- the xpath expression evaluates faster (`/Data/Document[@id=/Data/x]/@filename`)
- you could create an XSD schema for it

I also question why you would want to put the variable `<x>` in the same document as the other data - if you already know in the input document which 'Document' element you need, why not remove the others?

Having said that, an xpath expression that does what you are asking for is:

```
/Data/*[local-name() = concat('Document', /Data/x)]/@filename
```

Comment: Thanks it works great.  The reason for the strange schema is because the XML comes from another source.  The x variable is just an example of another source I have to identify the number of the document.